# the same block of elements visible one at a time and veriable naming

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some code for mobile and a desktop version. All the elements in the FORM are the same, but the block of code is visible one at a time depends on the screen size (one is always set to `display: none`),

```
<div id="desktop">
  <div id="content">
    <form method="post" name="form_name" id="id_form">
      <input type="email" name="name_email" id="id_email">
      <input type="hidden" name="hidden_input" value="submit_sub">
      <a href="#" id="btnSub">SAVE</a>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="mobile">
  <div id="content">
    <form method="post" name="form_name" id="id_form">
      <input type="email" name="name_email" id="id_email">
      <input type="hidden" name="hidden_input" value="submit_sub">
      <a href="#" id="btnSub">SAVE</a>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

//some JQ code
    $("#btnSub").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($("#id_email").val() == "") {}
    });

//some PHP code
  if (isset($_POST["hidden_input"]) == "submit_sub") {}
```

The above code looks the same for both desktop and mobile but in real all the elements are in different set up for mobile and desktop. My question is: can I use the same naming for IDs, NAMEs, or should I separate even if there are visible one at a time? If no do I have to change everywhere like different IDs or change for class, where I can leave the same naming? **The best would be to rewrite the above example with the correct naming.**

The reason I'm writing this question is that I've already written some code and have trouble to run it correctly, I don't know if I should change everything or the are some few things that should be only different. So, I'd like to know the main rules.

Comment: You should separate them - just use classes for the things under the id "desktop" and "mobile".

Answer (score 0):

As they are in different forms, you can use the same names to send the data, but you shouldn't use the same names if you need them in your JS code, try with classes.

IDs are unique to the page, use classes instead.

:)